# ¿Por qué no funciona el botón de "siguiente" generado desde JS a HTML y no puedo hacer andar el for... of?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, eventos, dom, click

No puedo hacer andar el botón que genero en el DOM y tampoco poder recorrer con el for... of y no encuentro el error...

```
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", startForm);

function startForm() {
    let title = document.getElementById("title");
    title.textContent = "Elige el producto que buscas.";

    let paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph");
    paragraph.textContent = "Ingrese su nombre";

    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.idName = "inputOne";

    let container = document.getElementById("mainContent");
    container.appendChild(input);

    button.textContent = "Siguiente"; 
}


var products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Aldrinne",
        type: "Buzo",
        price: 4200
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Recklezzy",
        type: "Joggin",
        price: 2800
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Julianne",
        type: "Leggins",
        price: 2500 
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Embassy",
        type: "Gorro",
        price: 2750
    }
]

let btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", addProduct);

function addProduct() {
    let container = document.getElementById("mainContent");
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(newDiv);

    for(products of products) {
        newDiv.innerHTML += `
        <p>Número de producto: ${products.id}</p>
        <p>Tipo: ${products.type}</p>
        <p>Nombre: ${products.name}</p>
        <p>Precio: ${products.price}</p>
        `
    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <title>Cotizador</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href=>Tienda</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="firstContainer" id="firstContainer">
            <div id="mainContent">
                <img src="img/maisie1.png" alt="Maisie Rugs">
                <h1 id="title">
                    Creamos alfombras únicas y personalizadas con la técnica punch needle.
                </h1>
                <p id="paragraph">
                    Ingresá las características del producto que estás buscando, conocé su precio y confirmá tu pedido.
                </p>
            </div>
            <button id="button">Comenzar</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>

        </p>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a ver tu código HTML, veo que tienes 2 variables que hacen referencias a lo mismo.

Comment: Ahí coloqué el código HTML @Euronymous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está aquí:

```
for(products of products) {
        newDiv.innerHTML += `
        <p>Número de producto: ${products.id}</p>
        <p>Tipo: ${products.type}</p>
        <p>Nombre: ${products.name}</p>
        <p>Precio: ${products.price}</p>
        `
    }
```

usas el mismo nombre para la variable de iteración y el elemento sobre el cual quieres iterar. Cambialo por esto:

```
    for(const product of products) {
        newDiv.innerHTML += `
        <p>Número de producto: ${product.id}</p>
        <p>Tipo: ${product.type}</p>
        <p>Nombre: ${product.name}</p>
        <p>Precio: ${product.price}</p>
        `
    }
```

Nota que el elemento a iterar es plural, y la variable de iteración es singular.